# How to get a React component's outerHTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a React Component and I want get its outerHTML to pass it on textbox.

Here is my code to get outerHTML:

```
var preview = document.getElementById("button-preview").outerHTML;
console.log(preview);
```

But, it return `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of null`

When I trying to change my code to

```
var preview = document.getElementById("root").outerHTML;
console.log(preview);
```

It doesn't shown error and return outerHTML of root. What is wrong?

Comment: try using react's "ref" attribute on nodes rather than using DOM selectors

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`refs-and-the-dom`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

On `componentDidMount` you can get the reference for  required element whose outer html  you want.

```
this.divEle.outerHTML //will give outerHtml.
```

In `render` put `ref` on required element.

```
ref={(divEle)=>this.divEle=divEle}
```

**example :**

```
class App extends React.Component{

     componentDidMount(){
       console.log(this.divEle.outerHTML);
     }

      render(){

        return (
          <div>
            <div style={styles}  ref={(divEle)=>this.divEle=divEle}>
              <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
              <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Working [`codesandbox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/2p5zjxjzmy)

Comment: How if the ref are outside or in another component? your example is one component

Comment: @AbidRakhmansyah can u please provide psudo code for requirement